# Ensuring ID uniqueness in a BibTeX file

Tags: bibtex

I am generating BibTeX files automatically from DOIs via the Crossref API.  I would like to concatenate the individual files into larger files.  However, service uses the year of publication as the entry ID, which is obviously not guaranteed to be unique.

Currently I am using a combination of the first author surname, the year of publication and as slightly mangled form of the DOI itself as an ID. The DOI would be unique on its own, but the name and year are there for legibility. An example might be

```
Smith2021_12.1234%2F12345678
```

Is there a better or more standard way of ensuring ID uniqueness in a BibTeX file?

Comment: You should absolutely avoid the character `%` in the ID, since this starts a comment in TeX and will lead to a lot of errors. Apart from that, using the DOI is probably a good idea, but the IDs will become quite long then. I used to just add a letter to the year, such as `Smith2021a`, but of course I would have to manually check for uniqueness.

Comment: Good point about the ```%```.  I wanted to use also the DOI-based identifier as part of the name of a file associated with an entry, so I needed to replace ```/``` with something and chose ```%2F```.  However, that is obviously not appropriate in the BibTeX file.  I could just tack a hash of, say, the title, onto the surname and date to get something like ```Smith2021_abcd0123```, although that seems a bit arbitrary.  I'll probably stick with the original DOI with ```/``` for the identifier and use some other mapping for the file name.